# Open graph stories through API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

[Apologies for poor quality question]

I am trying to pull open graph stories (public) published by my friends about an application. I realize that the typical filtering mechanism for feed (me/home?filter=app_321574327904696) does not work for Open Graph Stories.

Can someone help me find out the API that could filter OG stories for an application (or a keyword)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieving Open Graph actions is documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/#read

You need the `user_actions:<APP NAMESPACE>` permission from the user whose actions you wish to read, then you need to make an API call to `/<USER ID>/<APP NAMESPACE>:<ACTION TYPE NAME>` to retrieve the actions

For example, to retrieve [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com)'s 'pin' actions posted by a user, you need the `user_actions:pinterestapp` permission to be granted, then make an API call to `/me/pinterestapp:pin`

A sample output for me begins:

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": "<REMOVED ID>", 
      "from": {
        "name": "<REMOVED NAME>", 
        "id": "<REMOVED USER ID>"
      }, 
      "start_time": "2013-09-11T00:20:15+0000", 
      "end_time": "2013-09-11T00:20:15+0000", 
      "publish_time": "2013-09-11T00:20:15+0000", 
      "application": {
        "name": "Pinterest", 
        "namespace": "pinterestapp", 
        "id": "274266067164"
      }, 
      "data": {
        "pin": {
          "id": "<REMOVED PIN ID>", 
          "url": "http://pinterest.com/pin/<REMOVED PIN ID>/", 
          "type": "pinterestapp:pin", 
          "title": "TEST"
        }
      }, 
      "type": "pinterestapp:pin", 
      "no_feed_story": false, 
      "likes": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_like": true, 
        "user_likes": false
      }, 
      "comments": {
        "count": 0, 
        "can_comment": true, 
        "comment_order": "chronological"
      }
    }, 
  [...]
```